# can prototype method access constructor function's context (closure)

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var Tree = function() {

  // private variables in closure
  var fruits = 5;
  var smallBranches = 10;

  // public variables 
  this.bigBranches = 11;

  this.countFruits = function() {
    console.log(fruits);
  };

};

Tree.prototype.countBranches = function() {
  console.log(this.smallBranches);
  console.log(this.bigBranches);
};

var tree = new Tree();
tree.countFruits();
tree.countBranches();
```

The output is:
5
undefined
11

To keep the code reading simple, I prefer to add methods to prototype like `countBranches()` instead of inside construction functions like `countFruits()`. However, the disadvantage is that the prototype functions can not access Tree's private variables. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, the disadvantage is that the prototype functions can not access Tree's private variables. Is there a way to do that?

So you want a private variable which is not private. No, there is no way to do that. No more than any function can access some other function's internal state.

However, if your objective in making `smallBranches` private is to prevent it from being overwritten, you can keep it private while adding an accessor:

```
var Tree = function() {
   // private variables in closure
  var smallBranches = 10;
  ...
  this.getSmallBranches = function() { return smallBranches; };
};

Tree.prototype.countBranches = function() {
  console.log(this.getSmallBranches());
};
```

Or, if you prefer to be able to say `this.smallBranches` directly, make it an instance property with only a getter:

```
var Tree = function() {
   // private variables in closure
  var smallBranches = 10;

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'smallBranches', {
    get() { return smallBranches; }
 });
}

Tree.prototype.countBranches = function() {
  console.log(this.smallBranches);
  this.smallBranches = 42; // will fail
};
```

Comment: I agree that there is no way to access Tree's private variable in Tree.prototype.countBranches and still keeping it as private.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the approach of associating member functions through prototype, outside constructor is the standard approach for adding member function to a type in javascript. You are getting undefined, due to not associating `smallBranches` variables with current object. Thus, it ends up as a local variable and not accessible outside constructor function. You have to make it as a member variable.

Change you code, as given below :-

```
var Tree = function() {

  // private variables in closure
  var fruits = 5;
  this.smallBranches = 10;

  // public variables 
  this.bigBranches = 11;

  this.countFruits = function() {
    console.log(fruits);
  };

};
```

Comment: So your solution to not being able to access private variables in the constructor from methods defined on the prototype is to change the private variable to an instance member? Sure, but...

Comment: @torazaburo, Can you please elaborate your question ?

Comment: It's not a question, really. I'm just saying that the OP wants to keep `smallBranches` private, so making it an instance member instead is kind of a solution, but not really.

Comment: Probably, the intent of his code, is to make `smallBranches` as member variables, that's why he's accessing it with this qualifier in `countBranches` method. Otherwise, he might have accessed it without this qualifier. Thus, usage of `this` clarifies his intention.